# $\omega=df$ with $\omega$ compact supported: $f$ compact supported possible?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Taking $S$ a smooth surface, $\omega$ a 1-form with compact support that is exact ie $\omega=df$ with $f\in\mathscr{C}^\infty(S)$. Is it always possible to have $f$ with compact support?

Comment: Think about the simple case $S=\mathbb R.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Ok taking $U=S\setminus\text{Supp}(\omega)$ one has $df=0$ on $U$ so (reasoning on charts) $f$ constant equal to $\lambda$ on $U$, so one has $f-\lambda$ compactly supported and $\omega=d(f-\lambda)$: correct?

Comment: Be careful - is $U$ necessarily connected?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I correct: taking $U=S\setminus\text{Supp}(\omega)$ one has $U=\coprod U_i$ with $U_i$ connected and for each $i$ $df=0$ on $U_i$ so (reasoning on charts) $f$ constant equal to $\lambda_i$ on $U_i$, so taking $g=f-\lambda_i$ on each $U_i$ one has $g$ compactly supported and $\omega=dg$: correct?

Comment: Ok it's stupid, $g$ is not defined on $\text{Supp}\omega$... I continue to think about it

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis So it is not possible: I can't get shortly the formula but with a function like arctan but constant out of $[-1,1]$, then $\omega=f'$ can't be $g'$ with $g$ compactly supported because $g=f+constant$. Correct?

Comment: Yup, that's the idea! If you let $\phi$ be a positive compactly supported bump function, then $\omega = \phi \partial_x$ should work as a counterexample. You'll have to adjust it a bit to get a counterexample on a surface ($\mathbb R^2$ is probably easiest), but hopefully you can figure it out.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis but on a surface, don't we have that $S\setminus\text{Supp}(\omega)$ has only one non compact component so that my first idea works?

Comment: I mean a non compact surface

Comment: Depends on the surface and the support! I was wrong about $\mathbb R^2$; but the cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ will behave similarly to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So clear! Thanks